# PDF Javascript for Custom Stamp not working in Adobe Reader DC

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat, pdfstamper

Code below is for a custom stamp in Adobe Reader. This code is for a row of 3 text fields in the stamp table.

What it does: Asks for user input in a javascript window when stamp is placed. Once submitted, the text fields in the table of the custom stamp are filled with input.

Problem: It works in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI for all 3 fields. But fails to work for anything other than the first field in Adobe Reader DC. Resulting in the other 2 fields being blank.

The fact the first field works means that my code is fine up to the bottom part (" THIS PART HERE!"). Any help here in fixing or letting me know another way to define field values with user input would be appreciated :)

From what I heard ( [PDF JavaScript does not work in Adobe Reader DC but all other Readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370858/pdf-javascript-does-not-work-in-adobe-reader-dc-but-all-other-readers) ) the new Adobe Reader DC is quite strict on javascript syntax.

```
var dialog = {
        noz8Value: "",
        fa8Value: "",
        fl8Value: "",

        commit:function (dialog) { // called when OK pressed
                var results = dialog.store();
                this.noz8Value = results["txt1"];
                this.fa8Value = results["txt2"];
                this.fl8Value = results["txt3"];
        },     

        description:
        {      
                name: "8 Nozzle Load",    // Dialog box title
                elements:
                [      
                        {      
                                type: "view",
                                elements:
                                [      
                                        {      
                                                name: "1st Nozzle ID: ",
                                                type: "static_text",
                                        },     
                                        {      
                                                item_id: "txt1",
                                                type: "edit_text",
                                                width: 300,
                                                height: 30
                                        }, 
                                        {      
                                                name: "Fa (kN): ",
                                                type: "static_text",
                                        },     
                                        {      
                                                item_id: "txt2",
                                                type: "edit_text",
                                                width: 300,
                                                height: 30
                                        },
                                        {      
                                                name: "Fl (kN): ",
                                                type: "static_text",
                                        },     
                                        {      
                                                item_id: "txt3",
                                                type: "edit_text",
                                                width: 300,
                                                height: 30
                                        },
                                ]      
                        },     
                ]      
        }      
};

// THIS PART HERE (below)
//Line below Runs dialog function (prompt window) if stamp is placed down

if(event.source.forReal && (event.source.stampName == "#nozzle"))
{
  if ("ok" == app.execDialog(dialog))
  {
    var cMsg = dialog.noz8Value;
    event.value = "\n" + cMsg;
    event.source.source.info.noz = cMsg;

    var cMsg2 = dialog.fa8Value;
    this.getField("fa8Field").value = cMsg2;

    var cMsg3 = dialog.fl8Value;
    var test1 = this.getField("fl8Field");
    test1.value= cMsg3

 // Above I tried 3 different ways of linking the user input as the field's `value.`   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

Without event.source.source.info.noz = cMsg; the code works. The older versions worked fine and were more lenient. DC is strict.

```
if(event.source.forReal && (event.source.stampName == "#nozzle"))
{
  if ("ok" == app.execDialog(dialog))
  {
    var cMsg = dialog.noz8Value;
    event.value = "\n" + cMsg;

    var cMsg2 = dialog.fa8Value;
    this.getField("fa8Field").value = cMsg2;

    var cMsg3 = dialog.fl8Value;
    var test1 = this.getField("fl8Field");
    test1.value= cMsg3

  }
}
```